# auto movable gallery in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash-cs4

i have to develop one image gallery in flex, [image]

this is how it looks, wht i have to do, is to make it run, like it keeps running, from left to right,(the items shown here should move from left to right) 
i am using repeater in an hbox, can u help me by telling, how to make it movable?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Increse `horizontalScrollPosition` property of the box on timer or in each frame until it reaches `maxHorizontalScrollPosition`.

Comment: do u hav n e working demo, coz the maxHorizontalScrollPosition, i m not getting this property, wht i m doin is, i m removing the last element from the hbox,

Comment: private function init():void{
 dataService.send();
 timer = new Timer(1000);
 timer.start();
 timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
}
private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
movingHbox.addChildAt((movingHbox.removeChildAt(movingHbox.numChildren-1)),0);
}

Comment: this init(), i m calling on creationComplete of Application, ryt, than on timer, i adding child box, last child to first postion, this gives a flickring effects...k, no first i try wht u have suggested,